# Symfony2 cache warm up issue

Tags: symfony, capifony

I have an issue when I execute capifony command: `cap deploy`.

When the error happens I get this output:

```
  * 2013-10-03 18:32:39 executing `symfony:cache:warmup'
--> Warming up cache
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' sh -c 'cd myapp && php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug'"
    servers: ["127.0.0.1"]
    [127.0.0.1] executing command
*** [err :: 127.0.0.1] No entry for terminal type "unknown";
*** [err :: 127.0.0.1] using dumb terminal settings.
*** [err :: 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  require_once(myapp/app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in myapp/app/console on line 12
*** [err :: 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'myapp/app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in myapp/app/console on line 12
    command finished in 567ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf myapp; true"
    servers: ["127.0.0.1"]
    [127.0.0.1] executing command
    command finished in 182ms
```

I have to indicate that my deploy.rb looks like this:

```
set :application, "PT"
set :domain,      "MY IP"
set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/#{application}.es"
set :app_path,    "app"


set :repository,  "https://github.com/trepafi/repo.git"
set :scm,         :git

# Server
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
set :user,      "root"
set :domain,    "#{domain}"


set :model_manager, "doctrine"

role :web,        domain                         
role :app,        domain, :primary => true       

set  :keep_releases,  3
set :deploy_via, :rsync_with_remote_cache

logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL


# S2.4
set :use_composer, true
set :vendors_mode, "install"
set :shared_files,      ["app/config/parameters.ini"]
set :shared_children,   [app_path + "/cache", app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads", "vendor"]
set :update_vendors, true
```

I guess that it's an error clearing the S2 cache, How should I give permission to the corresponding folders?

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution, it was because the new S2 version. The shared files was renamed from parameters.ini to parameters.yml

```
set :shared_files, ["app/config/parameters.yml"]
```